# Animated graph of ODE

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I am attempting to create an animated graph by plotting specific points form 2 column vectors buy am having issues.

I have attempted to use the pause, drawnow, changing my vectors and am still having trouble with my code not working. I have got my vector in a for loop which specifies the points needing to be plotted.

Using ODE45 I have made a column vector with 2 rows.

```
grid on
func=plot(t,x);
%set(gca,'XLim',[0 tmax])
for i=1:length(x)
    set(func,'XData',x(1,i),'YData',x(2,i));
    drawnow
end
```

I expect the output to be an animated graph, but currently, all that I'm getting is either a nonanimated graph, or a bunch of errors saying that I am exceeding the array bounds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using `plot` with a single point. The default plotting style for `plot` is to not show individual points, but to connect the input data with lines.

Either change the [`LineSpec`](https://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/plot.html#btzitot-LineSpec) property to e.g. `'o'`:

```
func = plot(x(1,1), x(2,1), 'o');
```

or use the `scatter` function to plot individual points:

```
func = scatter(x(1,1), x(2,1));
```